# Please explain the meaning of this quote

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please explain the meaning of the boldfaced part of the following quote from *The House at Pooh Corner* by  A. A. Milne:

> One day when Pooh Bear had nothing else to do, he thought he would do
> something, so he went round to Piglet's house to see what Piglet was
> doing. It was still snowing as he stumped over the white forest track,
> and he expected to find Piglet warming his toes in front of his fire,
> but to his surprise he saw that the door was open, and **the more he
> looked inside the more Piglet wasn't there.**

Comment: ... the more he looked inside the more *[certain he became that]* Piglet wasn't there. It's a humorous style of writing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because interpretation at this level (of unusual literary devices) belongs on Literature.SE.

Comment: I too thought about closure but on reflection believe that the question is about usage of the construction "the more ... the more ..." and the logical aspects of it. And therefore it relates well to discussion of grammar and usage, so I answered it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of Milne’s endearing ways of emphasising a simple statement that might have dully said  *… he looked and Piglet wasn’t there*”. It works in at least three ways. Others may see more.

The first is that it parallels statements such as “*The more I see of her, the more I like her*”, which says that as I see new aspects of her, I feel greater appreciation of her. This sentence creates a statement that is true even when two things change: seeing and liking increase together. The changes reflect each other. Milne’s statement is constructed in the same way but is applied whimsically to two things that do *not* change together. Pooh looks and Piglet is not there. And no matter how much longer Pooh looks, Piglet is not there.

The second is similar and applies to the way that Pooh does his looking. If we imagine him to look, see nothing, close his eyes and look again, we may say that he has looked twice. On each occasion, Piglet is not there. It is then an amusing logical conclusion to say that Pooh looked twice and Piglet was not there twice. More looks will not change anything but we may still say that the more Pooh looked, the more Piglet was not there. Or that the more {times} Pooh looked, the more {times} he was {found} not {to be} there.

Third, at the emotional level, there is implied growing disappointment. Pooh expected to see Piglet, but as he looks and sees nothing, his expectations dwindle and his disappointment grows. The more he looks, the more he is disappointed at Piglet’s absence.